# how to hide custom button when editing mode is enabled?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I made a custom button using drawRect: and put it in my headerview for my tableview. I want the custom button to be hidden when editing mode is selected. i know i can do that by using the method:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

but for some reason, my button isn't actually dissapearing when I either 1) set it to nil, 2) or use the button.hidden property. Here is my code:

TableViewController.h:

```
@interface ToDoTableViewController : UITableViewController <Properties2ViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>{
    addButtonView *button;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *taskArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *completedArray;
-(IBAction)addCell:(id)sender;
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *headerView;
    UIView *seperatorView;

    CGRect testFrame = CGRectMake(280.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0);
   button = [[addButtonView alloc]initWithFrame:testFrame];

    NSString *sectionTitle = @"Incomplete Tasks";
    NSString *section2Title = @"Completed Tasks";
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:25];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 320.0, 40.0);
    headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:label.frame];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGRect sepFrame = CGRectMake(0, headerView.frame.size.height-2, 320, 1);
    seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sepFrame];
    seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    [headerView addSubview:seperatorView];

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            label.text = sectionTitle;
            [headerView addSubview:label];
             [headerView addSubview:button];
            break;
        case 1:
         label.text = section2Title;

            [headerView addSubview:label];
          // if (completedArray == nil)
            //   headerView.hidden = YES;
            break;

    }
    return headerView;
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if([self isEditing]){
        button.hidden = YES;
    }else {
        button.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

---EDIT----

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if([self isEditing]){
        button.hidden = YES;
        [[self tableView] reloadData]; //shouldn't this make the button dissapear?
    }else {
        button.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the table view is reloaded your code will recreate the entire header, including creating a new button. So you may have set the old button to hidden and then it gets destroyed and replaced by a new, visible, button.

When returning the header, either create it once and always return the same instance, then changing the `hidden` property should work. Or, check if the table `isEditing` each time the header is created and decide what to do as a result.

---

Let's go with the more efficient header reuse option:

1. Create a property to hold the header view(s) - an array.
2. In `viewDidLoad` create the header views (using your current code, but moved to a different method).
3. Add the header views to the property (ensure you initialise the array first)
4. Change `viewForHeaderInSection` to just return the header from the array (based on `section`)
5. In `setEditing:` iterate through the array and hide/show each button

(You could store the buttons in another array to make that easy)

Comment: i updated the main post with what i changed.

based on your feedback, why doesn't this work then? i am making the button hidden then reloading the view so shouldnt it hide the button?

Comment: You need to change `viewForHeaderInSection` for it to work. If you always recreate the button in `viewForHeaderInSection` then setting the old button to hidden is always lost. Changing `setEditing:` can't solve the issue.

Comment: how would I create the header once and return the same instance as you said? (based on my current viewForHeaderInSection